# Align one face to another face of object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

How can one object 'A' (activated in edit mode) be rotated to align it to the face of other object highlighted with pink colour.

[image]

Comment: Does using `Snap To Face` instead of `Snap To Grid` (default) work in this instance?

Comment: What do you mean by aligned? Supposing you mean with all 3 local axes parallel, you have 2 options I can think about:

1) As @NoviceInDisguise suggested use snap to face and make sure you select the button next to the snapping option: "Allow rotation with the snapping target" is the caption and it shows a sphere with a beam as an icon. After that translate accordingly

2) In case the pink object was previously rotated and the rotation wasn't applied yet you can copy the rotation parameters to the selected object and translate if needed :)

Answer (score 1):

1. In Object Mode select the plane that you want to align (the one that you want to change).
2. Add the second plane to the selection so that it is the active object.
3. In the 3D View Properties panel right click on one of the Rotation values and select 'Copy to Selected from' the pop-up menu and they will have matching rotation values.

I think that there are several ways to do this depending on the situation. This method may not work for all scenarios but it will work for two planar objects.

[image: Align two planes which are separate objects]